# Query funciona pero PHP no regresa los valores

Tags: php, ajax, sql

Hola estoy haciendo una petición a searchRand.php, en el php hago una query para obtener datos. Y la guardo en la variable $to_return. Pero al momento de regresar el valor de $to_return no devuelve nada. Estando en el php mando imprimir la variable $to_return antes de regresarla y si contiene valores pero el ajax no recibe nada. Por favor ayuda no se que está pasando.

Codigo de ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "access/searchRand.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        }
    });
 });
```

Codigo PHP:

```
<?php
require 'dbconn.php';

if($qry = $conn -> query('SELECT * FROM producto')){
    while($row = $qry -> fetch_assoc()){
        $to_return[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($to_return);
    $conn->close();
}else{
    $conn->close();
    return json_encode(array('status' => 'internal error'));
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Te has asegurado de que la llamada AJAX efectivamente esté llamando al archivo .php? Podrías probar a dejar el PHP limpio con por ejemplo un **echo 'Se llama'** para descartar que el error sea en la llamada.

Comment: Hola gracias por comentar, ya probe lo que mencionas y si llama al php

Comment: Estás declarando la variable $to_return dentro del bucle while. Podrías probar a inicializarla fuera. Pueden andar por ahí los tiros. Para asegurarte de que estás llegando al **echo** en tu código, podrías concatenarle a ese mismo echo un string delante o detrás para ver si todo está yendo correcto y no es solamente que el json_encode($to_return) se está enviando vacío.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo pero tampoco funcionó, sigue sin recibir los datos el ajax. Pero la variable #to_return si tiene los valores de la query

Comment: No creo que sea, pero fijate que en el if tienes echo y en el else return

Comment: Tampoco funcionó, cambie el return por echo y viceversa

Comment: Y dices que **json_encode($to_return)**, justo antes de hacerle el echo contiene la cadena json correctamente. ¿Correcto?

Comment: No se si has añadido el último código, pero no veo por ningún lado que devuelvas el $to_return, que hagas un echo no significa que lo estés devolviendo, por lo que en el if te hace falta poner return.

Comment: Es una llamada AJAX, tengo entendido que el valor de retorno lo obtiene mediante un echo, no un return.

Comment: como tal si imprimo $to_return con echo imprime sus valores pero no se como imprimir el json_encode($to_return)

Comment: Vale, parece que ese es el problema. Guarda primero en una variable el **json_encode($to_return)** y luego le haces un echo a esa variable.

Comment: ok ya la guarde en una variable y la mando a imprimir pero no imprime nada. Usando el codigo para que me mande cual fue el error me manda "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Comment: El problema posiblemente esté en la manera en que estás almacenando las rows de tu query. Estás usando un array[] básico y por lo que leo en la documentación de la función json_encode(), con lo que trabaja es con arrays asociativos para poder construir correctamente la cadena json, dotándola de una clave => valor. Prueba a usar la función array() de php a la hora de almacenar el resultado de tu query.

Comment: Men ya funciono, enserio muchas gracias!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Tal como lo encontró @PHPMyguel, El error identificado es el uso de un array básico con json_encode().

---

Hay 3 puntos que te recomendaria para entender mejor que está pasando:

- **Manejo de errores:** No todo será perfecto. Definir una funcion de error en el ajax te permitira saber cuando algo falla.
- **Usar un solo punto de salida/retorno en el PHP**: Esto te da mas control del flujo de datos en una función.
- **Declarar las variables antes de usarlas**: Declarar `$to_return` en el ámbito donde va a ser usada, así el lenguaje lo permita de otra forma.

Algo como esto:

**código ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "access/searchRand.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
 });
```

**Código PHP:**

```
<?php
require 'dbconn.php';

$ret_val="";
if($qry = $conn -> query('SELECT * FROM producto')){
    $to_return[] = "";
    while($row = $qry -> fetch_assoc()){
        $to_return[] = $row;
    }
    $ret_val = json_encode(array("data" => $to_return));
    $conn->close();
}else{
    $conn->close();
    $ret_val = json_encode(array('status' => 'internal error'));
}

echo $ret_val
?>
```

**Código PHP simplificado (sugerido por @A.Cedano):**

```
<?php
require 'dbconn.php';

$ret_val=array();
if($qry = $conn -> query('SELECT * FROM producto')){
    $to_return[] = "";
    while($row = $qry -> fetch_assoc()){
        $ret_val[] = $row;
    }
    $ret_val = json_encode(array("data" => $to_return));
}else{
    $ret_val["status"] = 'internal error';
}

$conn->close();
echo json_encode($ret_val)
?>
```

Comment: Usando lo que me dices me manda el siguiente error "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Comment: Al parecer el problema es en el JSON (como mencionó @PHPMyguel). Prueba haciendo echo justo antes del rerurn para ver como está el formato.

Comment: No imprime el el Echo de $ret_val

Comment: Gracias por mencionarme en la respuesta. Si ya modificases el código que expones añadiendo la modificación necesaria para que funcione sería perfecto, a fin de que quede bien registrada la solución.

Comment: Aún el código se puede mejorar: puedes declarar `$ret_val=array();` desde un principio. Luego, en el 1er `while` pones simplemente: `$ret_val[]=$row;` el cierre de la conexión lo dejas para el final. En el `else` pones: `$ret_val["status"]='internal error';`
  Y al final, fuera de todo, cierras la conexión y devuelves el resultado: `$conn->close(); echo json_encode($ret_val);` Son al menos 5 líneas de código menos y un programa más claro.

Comment: @A.Cedano Tienes razón, se puede simplificar. Gracias, lo añadiré.

Answer (score 1):

Estás especificando que el fichero devuelve un JSON, cuando en tu código (si la conexión no funciona), no devuelve nada.

**¿Por qué?**

Estás intentado capturar diractamente el resultado de searchRand.php vía ajax,cuando searchRand.php no devuelve ningún resultado si falla la conexión. Si yo ejecuto tu función vía php, me va a devolver el resultado correctamente (por que realizas un return), ya que php entiende tú código, sin embargo, una navegador (o otras interfaces de acceso que no utilicen php) no.

**¿Cómo lo soluciono?**

En tu código, simplemente cambia el return por echo:

```
<?php
require 'dbconn.php';

if($qry = $conn -> query('SELECT * FROM producto')){
    while($row = $qry -> fetch_assoc()){
        $to_return[] = $row;
    }
    $conn->close();
    echo json_encode($to_return);
}else{
    $conn->close();
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'internal error'));
}
?>
```

También fiajte que estás realizando un POST sin pasarle `data`, POST se utiliza para enviar datos, para solo recibir tienes que utilizar GET.